# simple ANSI C histogram function for 1D array of double-precision data?

Tags: c, histogram

Is there a generic solution out there to create a 1-D histogram array of data from an input 1-D array of double-precision data?

Not looking to plot the histogram in C, I just need something to create the histogram 1-D array by binning the data.

Could someone help me understand what the binning (e.g. loop) code may look like in C? Assume the min and max data points are known and we want to use a variable number (e.g. `hist_pts`) of different bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* bin = calloc(hist_pts,sizeof(int));
float interval = (float)(max - min ) / num_bins;
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    bin[ (int)((value[i]- min)/interval) ]++;
//don't forget to `free(bin) after you use it.
```

Comment: Thanks AShelly, is N the number of elements in array `value`?

Comment: @ggkmath No, it is the number of samples.

Comment: @AShelly - consider revising this answer.  num_bins is used in a way that suggests it is a variable.  C99 permits variable length arrays, but does not permit that sort of initialization.  If num_bins is an integer variable, interval will be a int - which may not be what OP intended. If num_bins is not integer, it will not compile.

Comment: Which should be the same thing, @beginner

Comment: good point, @Throwback1986.  Missed the "variable `hist_pts`" part.  Correcting.

Comment: Ah, yes. `values` is the array of samples.

Comment: Thanks Throwback1986. Yes, the number of bins will be integer, but the bin-width will be double-precision. Also, I'll be doing ANSI C, as CentOS 5 doesn't fully support C99 yet, although simply understanding the loop is primary goal.

Comment: Consider ensuring that interval is a float by casting num_bins to a float in line 2 above.  Otherwise, the resulting integer truncation may partition the domain in a way you might not intend.

Comment: C99 has been in GCC for a while (assuming you are using gcc...).  See this page for more information: http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Comment: @Throwback1986, the cast is already there on the numerator.  [A float divided by an int results in a float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx).

Comment: Yes, C99 has been in GCC for a while but the most recent GCC available in CentOS 5 (I'm using 5.7) is GCC 4.4.4, which isn't fully C99 compliant. I was suprised too. There's no binary available for anything newer, and I can't see myself bootstrapping to install a more recent version if it's not in yum or rpm.  See: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html

Comment: @AShelly, While the link you specify refers to C++, I've confirmed that you are correct for contemporary versions of C/C99 when compiled under gcc.  I understood that implicit type conversion would not occur in this case (you learn something new every day!)

Comment: @Throwback1986, this has been true since the first days of ANSI C: 3.2.1.5 " First, if either
operand has type long double, the other operand is converted to long
double .  Otherwise, if either operand has type double, the other
operand is converted to double.  Otherwise, if either operand has
type float, the other operand is converted to float."

Comment: And something similar was true for K&R C also: for any operation involving a float or double, all operands were converted to doubles.

Comment: Thanks AShelly for taking the time to post your answer above, it's working beautifully.

Comment: I don't think your interval is correct, since a value equal to max would increment the value one past the last bin. I suggest you change it to float interval = (float)(max - min ) /(num_bins-1);